# wp_remote_get vs. fetch_feed ? which is the better for performance?

Tags: feed, wp-remote-get

I m trying **to share my web site contents** for other web sites using by external loop file or rss file.

when i asked some questions about `wp_remote_get` function ; @Serkan suggest to me , using `fecth_feed` methot / function etc. (check the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13190156/wordpress-remote-get-function-usage).)=

I really confused , which one i should, which one is better way for high performance, could anyone explain it why ?

Thanks.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because the _solved_ status is visible the moment you tick the green check mark. That should never be part of the title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Neither are high performance, and they do different things.

`fetch_feed` is for grabbing feeds RSS feeds etc, `wp_remote_get` is for grabbing arbitrary items.

Neither are fast, and the performance difference between each is negligible or irrelevant, but technically `fetch_feed` is slower than `wp_remote_get`, not because it's faster or slower at grabbing over the network, but because it uses SimplePie to parse the feed ( which you'd end up using anyway if you used `wp_remote_get` on a feed ).

So even using `wp_remote_get`, you'd get the Feed in the same amount of time, but then you'd have to write the code to process it afterwards, and I'm sure the SimplePie people will be faster as they've had more time to optimise and test than you.

So if you're grabbing an RSS or Atom feed, use `fetch_feed`

If you're grabbing html files, images, or other files, use `wp_remote_get`

Why don't you use one of the feed aggregation plugins instead of reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I complatelly understood what you mean, what sould i do. Thank you so much your great answer @Tom. Bu i really dont want to use, any plugin in my Wordpress project. I think using your classes and functions instead of using plugin. Thank you so much again your great answer.